# Merge sort analyzing

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

Is there a different in the number of comparisons between merge sort in different case ?
For example ,

Case 1 : if I divide the array 2 parts and same size  T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/2)+n/2+n/2-1=T(n/2)+T(n/2)+n-1

Case 2 : T(n)=T(n/4)+T(3n/4)+(n/4)+(3n/4)-1=T(n)=T(n/4)+T(3n/4)+n-1

Since for merging 2 sub-array(let's say length m,n) I have to make at least  m+n-1 comparisons, then I think the answer is yes but I am not sure.

And what's about dividing the array into $k$ sub-arrays in each iteration?

Is there a an optimal dividing for getting the lowest **number of **comparisons ?****

I hope this is not a silly question, thanks!

Comment: The solution to case 1 is `T(n) = n log2(n)`. What's your solution to case 2?

Comment: @user3386109 T(n)=nlog4(n),  so case 2 is better ?

Comment: Hmm, I'd say `T(n) = n log1.33(n)` because `T(3n/4)` dominates `T(n/4)`. So case 1 is better. In fact, the 3/4 1/4 split is precisely the reason why quick sort performs poorly for some inputs. The more lopsided the split, the slower it gets. The worst case is `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(1) + n-1 + 1 - 1` which translates to `T(n) = n^2`.

Comment: @user3386109 If quicksort always splits 3/4 1/4, it doesn't really perform poorly, does it? That seems to be a rather *normal* and *good* split for it.

Comment: @KellyBundy To put a number on it, the 3/4 1/4 split is more than 2.4 times slower than a perfect 50/50 split. It's "more than" because I'm not accounting for the time needed to sort the 1/4 array. Now you might think that 2.4 isn't bad enough to be classified as "performs poorly", and that's ok. But then it's just a matter of opinion as to where to draw the line. For example, a 14/15 1/15 split makes quick sort run an order of magnitude slower than 50/50.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, when I hear *"quick sort performs poorly for some inputs"*, I think of quadratic runtime. Compared to that, 2.4 or an order of magnitude are really not bad. Also, typical quicksort doesn't achieve a perfect 50/50 split, does it? So it's not appropriate to compare against that. Looks like when you pick a pivot randomly, you average a 3/4 1/4 split, so compared to that, it's not 2.4 times slower but rather *the same* (and I suspect *always* getting 3/4 1/4 is *better* than just *averaging* that). Even median-of-three-random-elements seems to on average split 31/69.

Comment: @KellyBundy In essence, you are comparing quick sort to a bubble sort (or any other quadratic sort), and claiming that it performs well. That's true. I'm comparing quick sort to merge sort (or any other **true** O(nlogn) sort), and claiming that it performs poorly. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the best possible worst-case performance from dividing the array into equal-size parts. Consider the opposite in the extreme case: letting one part be size 1 and the other *n*-1. That gives you linear recursion depth, and quadratic time.

You get *n* log *n* (plus/minus some constant) *k*-way comparisons if you split into *k* subarrays of size as close to *n*/k as possible, where log is the base-*k* logarithm. Note, however, that logarithms of different bases differ only by a constant factor, so you always get O(*n* log *n*) as long as *k* is a constant.

**Update**: If you do a *k*-way split, you need a *k*-way merge, and there are different ways to code that. The most natural way is perhaps to repeat *n* times: find which of the *k* subarrays has the smallest not-yet-picked element and pick that. This way, what you get is a total of *n* log_*k* *n* *find-the-minimum-of-k-elements* operations. For each *find-the-minimum*, you need to make *k*−1 compare operations between pairs of elements, so the total number of compares is (*k*−1)*n* log_*k* *n*. **However**, it's possible to organize *k*−1 compares so that you get more information than just which one is the minimum (otherwise selection sort would be optimal)! Is it possible to find a way to do the merge in a way that gets the number of compares down to the optimal *n* log_2 *n* that you get with *k*=2? Maybe, but it would probably be a very complicated merge procedure.

Comment: Thanks , so while I have to minimize my  ***number of comparisons*** , what is best the case ? k=2 or k=4 ? according your answer the best possible worst-case performance is k=2 ?

Comment: I was a bit unclear in my answer (and in my head). I updated the start of the second paragraph. When you say number of comparisons, you mean 2-way comparisons (comparing 2 elements at a time). In order to merge k parts, you have to emulate comparing k elements at a time (with k! possible outcomes), and you can't gain anything by that, since it's a well-known fact that you can't get below O(n log_2 n) 2-way comparisons with any algorithm. So k=2 is optimal. It might be possible to somehow get to the optimal number of comparisons with larger k (not sure) but the code would be pretty complicated.

Comment: So k=2 is a better case than k=4 while i talk about number of comparison , but if I talk about O(nlogn) i can say they are the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure if k=2 is necessarily *better* than k=4, but it's definitely *not worse*. It's not entirely clear what the algorithm is for k>2, since you have to modify the merge part to work on k>2 subarrays and that can be done in different ways. One way would be to run every k-way comparison as a tiny mergesort, and then you should be back at the same number of 2-way comparisons as with k=2, plus possible overhead.

Comment: @njlarsson Agreed that `k >= 4` can be hard to analyze. However, k=3 *can* be analyzed, because choosing 1 of 3 requires 3 comparisons for the first, and 2 comparisons for each subsequent element (and there's no way to improve that). So k=3 is worse than k=2, because log3(n) has a constant factor of 0.63 compared to log2(n), but each element added to the merged output requires 2-ε comparisons. So overall, performance degrades to 1.26 times slower.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, you're right that this would be what happens if you do the merge in what's probably the most natural way. I added an update about this to my answer.

Comment: I'd say the typical way to do k-way merge is with a heap. In Python, that's even a builtin function (`heapq.merge`). I've tested some values of k in my answer now.

Comment: @user3386109 - choosing the smallest of 3 requires 2 comparisons. Choosing the smallest of k requires k-1 comparisons. A 4 way merge sort without heap requires 3 compares for each element moved, but only has 1/2 the number of moves of a 2 way merge sort, so the number of comparisons for 4 way is about 3/2 of the number of comparisons for 2 way. On a processor with 16 registers, 4 way without heap (nested ifs) is about 10% or so faster than 2 way, due to being a bit more cache friendly (the total number of moves and compares is about the same for 2 and 4 way).

Comment: @rcgldr Your method of merging the array is slightly different than what I had in mind. But for k=3 the number of comparisons (`2-ε` per element) is the same. I said nothing about k=4, other than it's harder to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about k-way merge sort, so I did an experiment, sorting 2<sup>16</sup>=65536 shuffled numbers with:

- Ordinary two-way merge sort.
- k-way merge sorts (splitting into k equal-size parts instead of 2) and using a heap for the k-way merge. From k=2 up to k=65536.
- Timsort (Python's builtin sorting algorithm), which is an optimized merge sort.

The tracked numbers of comparisons for each one:

```
two_way:        965,599 True
k_way(2):       965,599 True
k_way(4):     1,180,226 True
k_way(16):    1,194,042 True
k_way(256):   1,132,726 True
k_way(65536): 1,071,758 True
timsort:        963,281 True
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTbjtowEH3nK@aNhLXYhq1W24j9gH5DhCIDzuLEcVLblKWIb6fjS25shdRIyHjsOef4zNjt2Rwa@fLWqtutUE0Niso9DrxuG2VAH45FIdhsNtuzAsypyU/0HNE4nQF@NlYz9cEiSmAbgvbbwTtkm37KcVri71sfqQlIDAgmEYy4cRv3q6cDFwyz1lADysHcNcgB3UEWsM3KDS7QjG@ma07BkrYtk/vI7oq/LJfw9A7JJMyEZg9wLM1XHD7F2dkp7kw30CgrMB1MUMwclYRd75xGg3srw5k4pJ0r8PwMq6mgAOEt9@lZirJIwLLEcXzPiHu8ijAPvKGmla8ogSoocV1wYLT91TWB43sou57Krv4pW3BtIq990akvF3UalU9JvKg3MRRoWglc2ibEXVUc/89pdoJqDT@lGZozz7nkJs8jzURB4DcVRzZSbqNLF8RedOMoUwx5jTkwNcr7EM2WCtg1dUsV143UQwcMsWlrdHIHyrXHXd4TK9aqQD3i7PKNigaMrohc59YHtu8L07klRPSJTGfn7SfBP2jvH97aitMscf3iIJDVOinolgmCM30UJmC1iksTFfOLW0yTlytcRudMf5DrnIw0hGQEpvaOu7LTNsLKkFDZ1WKRvNrihvfFFXBsnX0rgqJ5eHVS5OgfoMwLt4di9kQJgRWB7wTeCCSvXnaFKEjkrb0H9x45gmLu78ClusaWpOop7KV4JIzX9sQ2p3c/nt1ufwE)):

```
from random import shuffle


def two_way(a):
    def merge(a, b):
        c = []
        i = j = 0
        m, n = len(a), len(b)
        while i < m and j < n:
            if b[j] < a[i]:
                c.append(b[j])
                j += 1
            else:
                c.append(a[i])
                i += 1
        c += a[i:] or b[j:]
        return c
    def sort(a):
        if i := len(a) // 2:
            return merge(sort(a[:i]), sort(a[i:]))
        return a[:]
    return sort(a)


def k_way(a, k):
    from heapq import merge
    def sort(a):
        if m := len(a) // k:
            return list(merge(*(sort(a[j*m:(j+1)*m]) for j in range(k))))
        return a[:]
    return sort(a)


class Int:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        global comparisons
        comparisons += 1
        return self.value < other.value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


def is_sorted(a):
    return all(x < y for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]))

def report(label, result):
    print(f'{label:13} {comparisons:9,}', is_sorted(result))

a = list(map(Int, range(2**16)))
shuffle(a)

comparisons = 0
report('two_way:', two_way(a[:]))

for e in 1, 2, 4, 8, 16:
    k = 2**e
    comparisons = 0
    report(f'k_way({k}):', k_way(a[:], k))

comparisons = 0
report('timsort:', sorted(a))
```

Comment: For a 4 way merge sort without heap (using nested if's instead), I get a compare count of 1,419,337. It's more compares, but since there are no heap operations, it ends up being faster, at least on a system with 16 registers, 8 of them used for current and ending indexes or pointers to 4 sorted runs to be merged.